# Set a Pathvariable in vimrc with whitespace

Tags: vim

I try to set up my Vim to use omnicppcomplete.

I followed the constructions [c++ code completion](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/C++_code_completion) to install it step by step. First I always get the error "Omni-completion (^0^N^P) Pattern not found". It was hard to figure out but now i know why it doesn't work.
Its because the following line in my vimrc

"set tags+=C:\Program\ Files\ (x86)\Vim\vim74\tags\cpp"

Vim can't handle the whitespaces in the path but i don't know how to get it work except to copy the tag-files into another directory (which i try and it worked).
I tried these options but nothing worked:

- C:\Program\\ Files\\ (x86)\Vim\vim74\tags\cpp
- C:/Program\ Files\ (x86)/Vim/vim74/tags/cpp
- C:\Program\< Space >Files< Space >(x86)\Vim\vim74\tags\cpp
- C:\Program\sFiles\s(x86)\Vim\vim74\tags\cpp
- C:\Program\\sFiles\\s(x86)\Vim\vim74\tags\cpp
- C:\Program/\sFiles/\s(x86)\Vim\vim74\tags\cpp

How do I have to write the path so omnicppcomplete can use the tags?

Comment: You probably should not be putting you tags files where the system stores Vim and it's runtime files. Probably best to store it local to your user directory so something like `~/tags/cpp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
let &tags .= ',C:\Program\ Files\ (x86)\Vim\vim74\tags\cpp'
```

An option `opt` can also be accessed as a variable `&opt`, which can be manipulated with `let`, can be used in expressions, and so on.  Unlike `set`, `let` has an almost sane syntax.

Also, paths in `tags` have to be separated by commas.

Comment: This way works fine and with you explanation i understand vim a little bit better :)

Comment: @AKludges It works, you just have to figure out the relevant escapes.  Good luck with that.

Comment: Thanks @lcd047, I will use :let instead, it is more powerful and doesnt need escaping :D

Answer (score 2):

See `:help option-backslash`. When using the :set command, you need to escape every backslash, *and* every space character, so you will need *three* backslashes to set paths with spaces! I.e. `set tags+=C:\\Program\\\ Files\\\ (x86)\\Vim\\vim74\\tags\\cpp`

Sometimes a nicer way, is to use a `:let` command, so that you can use single-quoted strings and don't need to escape as much. For example, `:let &tags.=',C:\Program\ Files\ (x86)\Vim\vim74\tags\cpp'`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try just to use `/` in paths, and escape whitespace like this '\ '.
For example I add this line in my vimrc:

```
set rtp=C:/Program\ Files\ (x86)/Vim/vim74/vim.exe
```

Than if you will command `:echo &rtp` you can see:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Vim/vim74/vim.exe
```

Note that here is no `\` before whitespace.